# if else statements using multiple radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, radio-button, getelementsbyname

What I want to do is create a questionnaire that has three yes or no questions.  If all three questions have 'Yes' selected, then I want one alert. If any of the questions have 'No' selected, then I want an alert specific to that question. I thought I had it, but I have missed something, somewhere. Can you please help?

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#getAnswersButton').click(function(Submit) {
        var groceryList = document.getElementsByName('groceryList');
        var equipTimeline= document.getElementsByName('equipTimeline');
        var whatTime= document.getElementsByName('whatTime');

    if (groceryList[0].checked && equipTimeline[0].checked && whatTime[0].checked) {
        alert("Great!  You’re all set! Let’s start cooking!  Just click the 'Next' button to continue.");

    } else if (groceryList[1].checked) {
        alert("Please select the 'Grocery List' link above and review the list to see what you may have missed.");

    } else if (equipTimeline[1].checked) {
        alert("Please select the 'Equip/Timeline' link above and make sure you have all of your tools.");                               

    } else if (whatTime[1].checked) {
        alert("Please select the 'Equip/Timeline' link above and make sure you have all of your tools.");                               
        }        
    }
});
</script>



<div>
    <form>
        <ol>
            <li><label for="ingredients">Do you have all of the ingredients listed on the grocery list?</label></li>                
            <p>
                <input type="radio" id="ingredients" name="groceryList" value="Yes" /> Yes
                <input type="radio" id="ingredients" name="groceryList" value="No" /> No
            </p><br>

            <li><label for="equip">Did you gather up all of the utensils, appliances, and tools that you will need to use?</label></li>             
            <p>
                <input type="radio" id="equip" name="equipTimeline" value="Yes" /> Yes
                <input type="radio" id="equip" name="equipTimeline" value="No" /> No
            </p><br>

            li><label for="timeToEat">What time are you preparing to serve dinner?  You need to subtract a <b>minimum</b> of 3 hours from that time.  Keep an eye on the clock! <i>(For example: if you are serving dinner at 7pm, then you should start preparing everything at 4pm.)</i></label></li>             
            <p>
                <input type="radio" id="timeToEat" name="whatTime" value="Yes" /> Yes
                <input type="radio" id="timeToEat" name="whatTime" value="No" /> No
            </p><br>
        </ol>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your question?  A question is usually a sentence that ends with a question mark that has something to do with programming.  Right now all you have is the question: "Can you help?".  The answer to that is yes!  Please post your specs to a "do-my-work-for-me.com" website, then go read this: http://www.sscce.org/  Please provide a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example.  And ask a short, specific question about that code.

Comment: My apologies for not knowing as much as you. I am completely new to this and trying to figure it out on my own.  I thought based on what I had and what I was seeing in a reference book, that my code would work. If I understood it all as well as you, I would have figured out the problem.With that said, I am trying to figure out why the script I have above does not give me the results I am looking for. I would give very SSCCE if I knew scripting well enough to know what to ask for. 
If it's such a bother to answer, please don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it! You're just missing a parenthesis to close the click function. Your last javascript lines should be:

```
    ... } else if (whatTime[1].checked) {
    alert("Please select the 'Equip/Timeline' link above and make sure you have all of your tools.");                               
    }        
  }); //This parenthesis was missing!
});
</script>
```

[Demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/sp2v5/)

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into JSFiddle and added the extra }); I also added the button to trigger the event. http://jsfiddle.net/sp2v5/

Comment: Chavakane, thank you for trying to help me out!  It's frustrating when I am so new to all of this and don't understand everything that I am looking at.

I added the extra }); but still cannot get the results I am looking for when I test it.  Is there something incorrect with the way I have the 2nd line coded? 
     $('#getAnswersButton').click(function(Submit) {
I keep thinking it is either that or in the statements where I have the variable[#}.
Do you see any problem with those?

Comment: Wow, it's works in your JSFiddle!  It didn't when I just added it on my code. Let me copy & paste and try it.